# kineticjs and phonegap - image wont load

Tags: cordova, kineticjs

I'm trying to load an image from the camera into a new images and pass into the kineticjs object but the image wont load. Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong please.

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
    var returnedImg = new Image();
    returnedImg.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    layer.clear();
    returnedImg.onload = function() {
        console.log('img loaded');
        mainImage = new Kinetic.Image({
            image: returnedImg,
            x: stage.getWidth() / 2 - 200 / 2,
            y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 137 / 2,
            draggable: true,
            startScale: 1
        }); 
        layer.add(mainImage);
        stage.add(layer);
    };      
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

regards

Comment: How is the imageData provided to onPhoneDataSuccess? Is it a call to Camera.getPicture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this line

returnedImg.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;

below the onload